# May I call Samuel Johnson a PhD?

Tags: phd, degree, titles, academic-history, honorary-degree

According to Wikipedia, [Samuel Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Johnson)

> was awarded an honorary doctorate in 1765 by Trinity College Dublin and in 1775 by Oxford University.

Also, apparently people referred to him as "Dr Johnson" back then.

May I put "PhD" after his name now, for example, in a caption?  Like this?

> Samuel Johnson, PhD (1709–1784)

Comment: I'd say calling an Honorary doctorate a PhD is confusing at best, but there may be conventions of which I'm unaware.

Comment: He was an LL.D. of TCD. There are no Oxford PhD's they are D.Phil. s. But there were none in Dr Johnson's day. Was he a DCL of Oxford?

Comment: My impression is that calling him "Dr. Johnson" was based on his erudition, rather than degrees. (For that matter, the degree system was not much like the modern one at that time!)

Comment: Related:  ["If I receive an “honorary doctorate” from a reputable university, would it be wrong to refer to myself as “doctor”?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/72504/if-i-receive-an-honorary-doctorate-from-a-reputable-university-would-it-be-wr).

Comment: @paulgarrett - Was it unusual for someone erudite with no doctorate to be called "doctor"?  Was it customary to call someone with a doctorate "doctor"?  How rare was it to earn a doctorate (I mean, not in the way Johnson did)?

Comment: @aparente001, I really don't have an authoritative answer to any of your comment-questions... but I do not recall _any_ other historical figure of that time being chronically referred to as "Doctor..." as was Johnson, and certainly some of them had passed the bar, and so on. Dunno, but Johnson seems to be singular in always being referred to in that fashion.

Comment: Dr Routh (1755-1854), of "verify your references" fame, is lightly later but always Dr Routh. I think in University circles it was absolutely standard to call holders of doctorates "Doctor". And even in London, see Pepys' diary and John Evelyn's.

Comment: @paulgarrett fwiw, the ODNB seems to suggest that "Dr Johnson" was popularised after he was awarded the LLD. That's not to say it was solely because of the doctorate, but it certainly wasn't entirely independent of it.

Answer (score 34):

No.

He was an LL D of Trinity College, granted 1765; and a DCL of Oxford, granted 1775.

See https://www.britannica.com/biography/Samuel-Johnson

Note: 
DCL= Doctor of Civil Law.
LL.D.= Doctor of Laws, that is of both the Civil and the Canon Law.

Comment: DCL = Doctor of Civil Law?  Is that why people called him "Dr. Johnson"?  I just found http://www.oxforddnb.com/view/10.1093/ref:odnb/9780198614128.001.0001/odnb-9780198614128-e-14918# which says the letters "MA" were put after his name when his dictionary was published.

Comment: He was awarded the Oxford Master of Arts just *before* the Dictionary was published. His biographer Boswell calls him Doctor because of the LL.D., look at the biography's title.

Answer (score 26):

I am not sure why you would want to do this, but it seems both anachronistic and misleading. Johnson was not awarded a PhD by either institution, and the degree he was awarded was not equivalent to a modern PhD.